# ¿Porque Firefox developer edition no precargar mi js antes de ejecutarlo?

Tags: firefox

Hace poco decidí utilizar el navegador Firefox delevoper Edition pero ocurrió algo extraño, al momento de ejecutar mi codigo este primero no precarga es decir

```html
<div>
  
  <script src="js0.js"></script>
  <script src="js1.js"></script>
 </div>
```

Supongamos que yo utilizo una función del js1.js en el js0.js al momento de ejecutar la función en mi js este dice que no está definida, pero si pruebo este en otro navegador como chrome si me deja utilizar la función ¿A qué se debe esto?

Comment: Se debe seguramente a la implementación del motor de Javascript que difiere según el navegador. Por otro lado, desde el punto de vista de performance de tu página, tener la lógica separada en diferentes archivos no es lo que se estila, precisamente por el comportamiento que observas en diferentes navegadores y por el simple hecho que por cada archivo es necesaria una petición `http`, lo cual añade tiempo de demora a tu aplicación. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ¿Como me recomiendas tener la logica para que no difiera en diferentes navegadores?

Answer (score 0):

La descarga de los archivos se realiza por procesos que transcurren en paralelo, por regla general no terminan descargándose de manera secuencial y a veces alguna descarga puede fallar.

Si una función de un *script* necesita otra que está en otro, tal ves deberías utilizar mecanismos que te permitan controlar el proceso de carga de los archivos, pero requiere código y algunas artimañas que no funcionan siempre. Es preferible evitar utilizar este método siempre que sea prosible.

[JQuery](https://jquery.com/) tiene la función `getScript` ([documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)), pero tarda un tiempo desde que lo descarga hasta que lo puedes utilizar. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565365/jquery-getscript-callback-when-script-is-fully-loaded-and-executed) hay un hilo con información sobre esta función.

Creo que la mejor opción es utilizar un único archivo de *script* para las funciones que compartirás entre varias páginas y utilizar alguno de los callbacks de JQuery, como su función `ready` ([documentación](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler)) o alguno de los otros métodos que proveen los navegadores, como el callback `DOMContentLoaded` (ver soporte [aquí](https://caniuse.com/?search=DOMContentLoaded)).

Comment: Precisamente me pasó con Jquery, con firefox developer edition quise utilizar la sintaxis de jquery como el tipico "$()" pero al utilizarla me salia que este no estaba definido obvimente los <scripts> estaban como yo lo muestro en mi ejemplo <script src="js0.js> era donde utilizaba el jquery y en js1.js supongamos que era la cdn de jquery

Comment: ¿Y has incluido la referencia a JQuery en tu documento?